# Using span like format for creating objects. Is that possible?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Why does span relationship query work with `get` and not with `create` is there a way I can make it work ?

Some background:

Currently I am doing something like

```
qm = questionModel.object.get(question=quest)
answer = modelInterviewAnswer.objects.create(patient=patientobj,question=qm )
```

Now I know something like this already works

```
modelInterviewAnswer.objects.get(patient=patientobj,question__question=quest )
```

My question is why does something like this only works with `get` and not with `create`

```
modelInterviewAnswer.objects.create(patient=patientobj,question__question=quest )
```

**Update:**

This is the error I get when I attempt to use

```
  modelInterviewAnswer.objects.create(patient=patientobj,question__question=quest )

    'question__question' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

so my question is why does `question__question` work with get but when i use it with create I get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, you have to specify what you mean by "it does not work". Theoretically it does work - you can indeed create objects by calling `RandomClass.objects.create(field1='field-1-value', field2='field-2-value')` and it works. If it does "work" for `.get()` and doesn't "work" for `.create()` (I assume you get some kind of an exception when trying that code), then one reason could be that `get()` retrieves and existing object from the DB and can fill all the required field values from the DB, while `.create()` inserts a new object into the DB and if some required values are missing, then you get an exception.
An alternative or a solution for that is not to use `create()` that is a direct DB command basically, but to use the Django intermediary model instance for creating an object. Basically the difference is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class RandomModel(models.Model):
    # NB! Required fields
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=32)


# This is how you want to do it
RandomModel.objects.create(field1='value')
# An error is returned because you didn't specify a value for field2 and this goes directly to DB

# An alternative:
obj = RandomModel(field1='value')
obj.field2 = 'value232'
obj.save() #  Only here is it saved to the DB
```

If you're looking for a more concrete answer, update your question accordingly.

EDIT:
Because the field `question` is in another model and you CAN NOT change another model's fields using the `create()` method of one model. However, you can filter existing objects based on their field values, using methods like `.get()`, `.filter()`, `.exclude()`.

To achieve what you want, you have to do the following (not the only way, mind you):

```
# if the question instance exists and you just want to change the question (kind of unlikely in my opinion?)
question_instance = QuestionModel.objects.get(#some-params-that-get-the-question)
question_instance.question = 'How the hell did we end up here?'
question_instance = question_instance.save()
# Proceed to create the other model

# if the question instance does not exist (more likely version)
question = QuestionModel.objects.create(question='Is this more like it?')
answer = AnswerModel.objects.create(answer='Yes, it is.', question=question)
```

Comment: @JamesFranco Edited the answer

Comment: Yeah thats how i am currently doing it ,  and i was curious if we could use spanning like queries in the save method (like `quest__question = "xx"`) and turns out we cant unfortunately (am i correct ?)